# How to decide input filter specifications for linear power supply design

Tags: transformer, emc, emi-filtering

I am newbie trying to design a precision linear power supply and I have already chose a transformer which will meet my output requirements. Now, I am not sure how to figure out what parts should I use for EMC/EMI filters for the input of the transformer from main's AC. I have basic knowledge about X and Y rated caps and common mode chokes but I am not sure what specification or ratings parts should I choose to go with a simple ac filter input stage before hitting the primary winding of the transformer. The transformer I am using is: https://my.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Triad-Magnetics/VPM18-2780?qs=bdQtRzgkM2RlDm%2FtY2Kgow%3D%3D

Comment: Are you sure you need EMC/EMI filtering to begin with? Also, since the transformer is a medical grade one, do you also need a medical grade EMC/EMI filtering? Do you need to pass official testing for EMC/EMI and/or medical grade devices?

Comment: the medical grade transformer is just one I chose which fits my budget and meets my required specifications. So, i do not need medical grade emc/emi filtering but it would be really good to design one which passes official testings for emc/emi.

Comment: It might pass EMC/EMI tests even without filtering too. It of course depends if you are making a linear or switch mode power supply. And if you still want an EMC/EMI filter, just buy one, they are designed to be safe so you don't have to know anything about X and Y rated caps or common mode chokes.

Comment: Designing a linear power supply. And the main point of the project is to learn by designing. That's why not trying to buy premade filters.

Comment: I am fine with that, but please bear in mind, that is the hazardous mains side of the circuit. Would you rather live dangerously and design it yourself while being unsure if it is hazardous and burns a house down, or simply buy a safe mains inlet component with switch, common-mode filter and fuse built-in?

Comment: @Justme I want to build it to learn the about designing these filters and mains protection circuitry.